# How to remove other boot loaders

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, ubuntu-10.04, linux-mint

I installed windows 7 on my laptop. Then installed Ubuntu 10.04(Not the wubi installation).
I installed 10.04 by directly booting into the cd.
Then here comes linux mint 9. I installed it inside Windows.
Now I have a problem. Those 3 operating system can boot. But they have their own boot loaders.
At first, after installing ubuntu. I only got the grub boot loader. Because I didn't install it through wubi. After installing linux mint inside windows. I got the default windows loader. 
And from there I can choose to either boot windows or linux mint.(There's no Ubuntu). I can only find the loader for ubuntu when I choose windows. After choosing windows I got the grub boot loader. And I can boot from either windows or ubuntu.
And when I choose linux mint from the first boot loader(windows loader). I'm also confronted with another grub boot loader. Choosing between windows and linux mint.

Is it possible to just have one loader and place all the os in there so that I won't have to go through all that just to load a certain os?

Would it decrease the performance of windows, ubuntu or linux mint. Since I have them installed on one partition?What are the other disadvantages of doing this?